# Differentiate figures from graphics

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, koma-script

I need to differentiate illustration from graphics. This is necessary due to the norms from my country.

So I have created a "\DeclareNewTOC" that worked fine:

```
\DeclareNewTOC[
type=graficosabnt,
types=graficosabnts,
float,
floattype=3,
name=Graphics,
listname={List of graphics}
]{lol}
```

I was able to make a list of this graphics using \listofgraficosabnts. But I need to put figures and graphics on the same list. I was able to do so using \captionlistentry[figure]{#1} on the graficosabnt, but it doesn't do what I need. It gives new numbers to the graphics.

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} %figuras


\DeclareNewTOC[%
type=graficosabnt,%
types=graficosabnts,% used in the \listof.. command
float,% define a floating environment
floattype=3,% see below
name=Gr\'{a}fico,%
listname={Lista de Gr\'{a}ficos}%
]{lol}

\renewcommand\thegraficosabnt{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{graficosabnt}}

\begin{document}

    \listoffigures

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \caption{test\_figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width= 0.2 \linewidth]{dummy}
        \label{a}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{graficosabnt}[H]
        \captionlistentry[figure]{test\_graph2}
        \centering
        \caption{test\_graph2}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width= 0.2 \linewidth]{dummy}
        \label{b}
    \end{graficosabnt}

\end{document}   % Fim.
```

I have the following result:
[image]

And I would like to have:

List of Figures

Figure 0.1 - test_figure . . . . .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
 1

Gráfico 0.1 - test_graph2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1

Comment: You could use \newfloat and \listof from the float package, but that mean separate lists for figures and graphics.

Comment: From the `caption` package manual: "There is also a starred variant, \captionlistentry* , which does not increment the <float type> counter."

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt While `\captionlistentry*[figure]` does not increment the `figure` counter it uses the current value of the `figure` counter. But in the example the entry should be for the `graficosabnt` counter with the right prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an uptodate KOMA-Script version:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}% should be the last package

\KOMAoptions{captions=above}

\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{%
  \csname listof#1entryname\endcsname\ #2~-~%
}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{lof},
  indent=0pt,
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=0pt
]{default}{figure}


\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=graficosabnt,%
  %types=graficosabnts,% not needed in this example
  float,% define a floating environment
  floattype=3,
  name=Gr\'{a}fico,%
  %listname={Lista de Gr\'{a}ficos}% not needed in this example
  tocentryindent=0pt,
  tocentrydynnumwidth,
  tocentrynumsep=0pt,
  tocentryentrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{lol}
]{lol}
\counterwithin{graficosabnt}{chapter}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ext@graficosabnt}{lof}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[!hb]
  \centering
  \caption{test\_figure}\label{a1}
  \includegraphics[width= 0.2 \linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!hb]
  \centering
  \caption{test\_figure}\label{a2}
  \includegraphics[width= 0.2 \linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\begin{graficosabnt}[!hb]
  \centering
  \caption{test\_graph2}\label{b}
  \includegraphics[width= 0.2 \linewidth]{example-image}
\end{graficosabnt}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Remarks:

- Use `\KOMAoptions{captions=above}` if you put all your captions in the source code above the figures, tables, ... The option ensures that the additional space between caption and content is inserted below the caption (and not above it). But note the option does not move the caption itself, so it must be at the right position in the source code. KOMA-Script classes also provide `\captionabove` and `\captionbelow`. See the documentation for more information.
- You can use all options of `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` also with `\DeclareNewTOC` if you add the prefix `tocentry` (example `dynnumwidth` -> `tocentrydynnumwidth`)
- `\ext@graficosabnt` stores where the listentries should go. If it is redefined to `lof` the entries for graficosabnt will appear in LoF.